# Необходимо ли использовать SurfaceView?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Тяну с помощью `Лоадера` с базы данные, после их необходимо отобразить на собственном графике, буду использовать свою View и рисовать по ним `Canvas`. Когда пользователь листает его влево-вправо график перерисовывается по новым данным. Вопрос, необходимо ли использовать `SurfaceView`? Будет ли без него подтормаживать `Activity`? И за какой промежуток тянуть данные из базы за один раз? На экране может одновременно отображаться примерно 10 объектов. Так один из них выглядит, когда получен из базы:

```
public class Object {
    private Calendar date;
    private int value1;
    private int value2;
    private int value3;
    private int value4;
}
```

Comment: зависит от кол-ва значений, это же очевидно

Comment: @metalurgus каких значений?

Comment: @metalurgus и много это сколько?

Comment: Я думаю, что пока не сделаешь оба варианта и не протестируешь, однозначный ответ - будет тормозить или нет дать затруднительно

Comment: Значений графика (точек). Все зависит от того, как рисовать.